# Media Query working.. but not on iPhone 5

Tags: iphone, background, media, stretch

Am I missing something here? if I take my desktop browser and size it to emulate the media query, the background is fixed, and relative to the screen, and the body scrolls over top of it... but when I view that page on my iphone, the background now stretches the entire length of the body of the page. What is going on here?!

http://i930.photobucket.com/albums/ad149/xesvuli420/WTH_zpse6ed336b.png

As you can see, somethings wrong... but what is it? Heres the code I am using:

background:transparent url("../images/plan.jpg") no-repeat fixed center; background-size: 100% 100%;}

Ive tried substituting cover, contain, auto.. everything I can think of... Its hard because its right when you size down a browser.

Please hep me..